# Tensorboard is not creating any files

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use tensorboard with pytorch lightning.

The code runs, but nothing gets created in the tensorboard logs folder.

Relevant (not complete) code:

```
class LightningClassifier(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,):
        self._train_accuracy = torchmetrics.Accuracy()

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        outputs, labels, loss = self._common_step(batch, batch_nb)
        self._train_accuracy(outputs, labels)

        self.log("training_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=False)
        self.log("training_accuracy", self._train_accuracy, on_step=True, on_epoch=False)
```

and

```
    tensorboard_output_folder = r"/my_path/to/tb_logs"
    assert os.path.isdir(tensorboard_output_folder)
    tb_logger = TensorBoardLogger(tensorboard_output_folder, name="my_logger")
    # Initialize a trainer
    trainer = Trainer(
        accelerator="auto",
        devices=[config.device],
        max_epochs=config.number_epoch,
        callbacks=[TQDMProgressBar(refresh_rate=20)],
        log_every_n_steps=1,
        logger=tb_logger
    )
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are expected to be found here:

`/my_path/to/tb_logs/my_logger/version_0`

Note that there is a "/" at the front, so this will go to the root of the filesystem. I'm not sure if this is what you did or it is because you replaced the real path with this for illustration. I'm mentioning just in case you have this typo in your real path but were looking at the working dir.

Otherwise, the logs will be saved at the cwd from where you run the python command. Here is what I get (with leading "/" removed from your path):

```
my_path/
└── to
    └── tb_logs
        └── my_logger
            └── version_0
                ├── checkpoints
                │   └── epoch=0-step=1.ckpt
                ├── events.out.tfevents.1662234245.quantumgrid.local.33442.0
                ├── events.out.tfevents.1662234245.quantumgrid.local.33442.1
                └── hparams.yaml
```

Hope this helps.